# posts_per_page in a tax_query

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

I want to show two latest posts of a taxonomy in a `front_page.php` template.

```php
$args_article = array(
  'post_type'             => ['text'],
  'post_status'           => ['publish'],
  'posts_per_page'        => 2,
  'tax_query'             => [
      [
        'taxonomy' => 'article-type',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'articulo',
      ]
   ]
 );
 $query_article = new WP_Query( $args_article );
```

It returns all posts instead two latest.

It works without `tax_query`:

```php
$args_article = array(
  'post_type'             => ['text'],
  'post_status'           => ['publish'],
  'posts_per_page'        => 2,
 );
 $query_article = new WP_Query( $args_article );
```

The loop is very simple (it is in Blade template syntax):

```
@while ($query_article->have_posts()) @php $query_article->the_post() @endphp
   @include('partials.content-owl')
@endwhile
```

Entire code can be reached [here](https://bitbucket.org/aitormendez/superbiajuridico/src/master/web/app/themes/sj/resources/views/front-page.blade.php).

And there is a provisional link with deployed site [here](https://stage.superbiajuridico.es/). There are three similar loops in the front page.

How can I get just latest posts with a `tax_query`? Thanks!

Comment: can u please show me your code with loop so i will check and update if anything is going wrong.

Comment: Sure! Please, look at the updated question.